# Web based SIP Softphone app with open source api

Tags: c#, lync

I am planning to build a web based softphone which can be used with any SIP server (now need to support Genesys). Can you please suggest any C# based open source solution?

I was exploring these option and heard about Lync client SDK for SIP interaction. Can I use Lync Client SDK to build SIP softphone which can register work with 3rd party SIP server like Genesys etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you have a Lync environment (hosted, on-premises, etc.) that is integrated via SIP with your Genesys platform - using a Session Border Controller or similar mechanism.

Unfortunately you can not communicate using the Lync Client SDK directly with a non-Lync platform.

Comment: without lync is it possible with any open source SDK. I need web based SIP Phone.

Comment: There's a number of open source SIP libraries (some with soft phones). Here's the first 3 I found on Google.  

[http://www.officesip.org/](http://www.officesip.org/)  
[http://www.pjsip.org/](http://www.pjsip.org/)  
[http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone.html](http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone.html)  

That should help you get started.